# Pre-signed url to upload file on DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to integrate #docusignapi into my website and was looking for a pre-signed upload mechanism. But their API don't talk about that (at least I haven't seen it anywhere).

Did anyone successfully managed to do that?

If you are not familiar with pre-signed upload, here's [a blogpost from Dropbox about how they propose that](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2019/01/new-file-upload-link-api/).

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve here?

Comment: @Drew I'm trying to avoid using my server as a proxy, without giving my DocuSign credentials to the end-user. Have a look on DocuSign blogpost, it's well explained what pre-signed URL helps to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does not offer a pre-signed upload feature at this time.

You can upload documents via the [Envelope::create](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create) API call in the body of the JSON object after being Base64 encoded.

You can see this via scenario 2 in the example launchers (see below).

You can also upload document(s) in binary mode via a multi-part mime transaction. See scenario 10 in the example launchers.

Documents can also be uploaded in separate transactions if the envelope is first created in draft mode.

The example launchers are listed below. Each includes 14 or more scenarios.

C# -- https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core

PHP – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant

Java – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant

Node.js – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant

Python – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant

Ruby – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-ruby-auth-code-grant

Curl (direct API) – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-curl

Answer (score 0):

If you want UI to upload documents to the envelope before Sending the envelope for ESigning, the you can use [Sender View](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender) for Draft envelope, with this soln. your customers need to come to your App, and then App can call this ESign APIs to generate one time URL, and load that URL in the browser to ask your users to upload the document on the Envelope.

Update:

There is one more option which can be used, but this will be only used if the recipient of the envelope has a DS Account, then you can add them as an Editor (Allow to Edit) recipient type in the workflow. When they will get email from DocuSign then they will login with their DS Credentials and can modify the envelope in same way as Sender of the envelope, with Editor Recipient Type, they can add/update Documents, add/update Recipients and their Tabs.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the use of the Sender View API in this case, as Sender View links are effectively the account holder's credentials.

Comment: Drew, I know its not recommended but its the only solution if someone does not want to do everything using API and want to use existing DS Functionality. And it is App which knows Sender Credentials, and once job is done then callback should take them back to App.

Comment: It's true that the app is the only place the credentials are stored. That said, when a user is in the sending session, it's trivial to 'break out' of Sending, access the web console and act as whoever is authenticated.